# htaccess - This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not like before, now there is a simple url applied in htaccess.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^Customer-cat(.+)/(.+)$ /Customer-cat.php?Mcat_id=$1&customCat=$2 [L]
```

Now I can't access the page and get redirect to 404 page (broken page)

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

When I remove Options +FollowSymlinks I get this message

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I go into httpd.conf and found mod rewrite is uncomment.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Is there other Modules should be enable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have follow symlinks otherwise mod_rewrite won't work at all. You should also include the removal of `Multiviews`. The rules you have is looping, because mod_rewrite will continue to run through the rules until the URI stops changing, and your target `Customer-cat.php` matches the same rule's pattern `^Customer-cat(.+)` so it just keeps getting applied. Add some conditions to prevent this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Customer-cat(.+)/(.+)$ /Customer-cat.php?Mcat_id=$1&customCat=$2 [L]
```